# How to use %run command to execute another notebook using file path?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Let's say I have two notebooks `nb1.ipynb` and `nb2.ipynb`. If they are in the same folder I can run one from another simply by, for example:

```
%run ./nb2.ipynb
```

But I wasn't able to get it run when they are in different folders. I tried to use the file path but couldn't get it work, perhaps because my file path has blank spaces. Code like this

```
%run ./'C:/myusername/My Folder/nb2.ipynb'
```

returns an error:

```
Exception: File `"./'C:/myusername/My.py"` not found.
```

Can you give a hint how to fix it?

EDIT: Following Devyl's suggestion, this works:

```
%run "C:/myusername/My Folder/nb2.ipynb"
```

Comment: ./ references to current folder try without it and without ‘

Comment: @Devyl Thanks, that worked, except that I need to use double quotation marks instead of taking them out. For some reason single quotations don't work.